# Using Secant method in python while trying to find the root for complex equation

Tags: python

my code :
import math

```
z = float(input("Enter 'es(T)' value : "))

def f(x) :    
    y=z-611*math.exp(5417*((1/273)-(1/x)))
    return y

def delta(x1,x2):

    y=x2-x1
    return y

def m_sec(x1,x2):

    y=(f(x2)-f(x1))/delta(x1,x2)
    return y 

def sec_method(x1,x2):

    while True :
        try :
            x3= x2 -(f(x2)/(m_sec(x1,x2)))
            return x3
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            break

first = float(input("Enter 'first' value : "))

second = float(input("Enter 'second' value : "))

for i in range(0,30):
    temp = sec_method(first,second)

    if z-f(first)!=0 :
        print (first, second, temp)
        first = second
        second =temp

    else :
        print ("The end!")
        break
```

when I use this code, the result only shows numbers getting smaller and smaller.
what im trying to do is to find root "x" which satisfies the equation z-f(x) ==0.

How can I solve this problem?